# View moves along with another view in relative layout?

Tags: android, xml

I have a following XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ce6517"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/relative" >

<ImageView android:id="@+id/upload_IV"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/upload" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/upload_TV"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Upload" android:layout_below="@+id/upload_IV"/>


<ImageView android:id="@+id/settings_IV"
    android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/upload" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/upload_IV"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/settings_TV"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/settings_IV"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/upload_TV"
    android:text="Settings" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

It looks like this:

[image]

**Question:** How to position TextView named "Settings" just below second icon? So if I make more margin on the second icon, the text will move along with it? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/settings_TV"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/settings_IV"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/settings_IV"
    android:text="Settings" />
```

Also, there's no need for the second `RelativeLayout`, you can just leave your views as children of the root view.

Comment: One more thing please. Now Text it is below desired ImageView, but it's not perfectly centered below. How do I do this?

Comment: Mmh for that, you better apply the margin to the text, and align the image; in this case you would `alignLeft` and `alignRight` the image to the text.